# Need help fixing this jQuery dropdown script

Tags: jquery

I'm working on a script for a dropdown menu. It's working fine so far, but I need to add one more thing and I can't figure it out. Here's the current script:

---

```
 $j('ul.menu > li').hover(

    function() { var ulHeight = $j('ul', this).height(); $j(this).children('ul').css({height: 0}).stop().animate({height: ulHeight}, 400); },
    function() { $j(this).children('ul').stop().animate({height: 0}, 400);   }
);
```

---

I need to to return the height of the UL to it's original size, and set the display to none, so it can run again. The way it is now, as the height is set to 0  on leaving, the next time the "ulHeight" is taken it's 0.

I tried it like this but no joy:

---

```
 function() { $j(this).children('ul').stop().animate({height: 0}, 400).css({height: ulHeight});   }
```

---

Anyone any ideas?

Comment: can you post a demo on http://jsbin.com?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sub menus aren't showing at all...

but ultimately, why reinvent the wheel? http://css-tricks.com/simple-jquery-dropdowns/ or [Superfish](http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/)

---

The only thing I would suggest, now that I've looked at your new code, is replace

```
.css({"display": "block"});
.css({"display": "none"});
```

with

```
.show();
.hide();
```

respectively, and you could use `.hover` instead of `.mouseenter` and `.mouseleave`

Check it out [here](http://pastebin.me/9943bb562344408fd3db2adef5d8954d)... I couldn't edit your code in jsbin (the edit window was 3 lines high and I couldn't scroll) so I reposted it to pastebin.

Comment: So I can learn how to make a wheel myself ;-) 

The sub-menus I've sorted separately as I wanted them flying out from the side as opposed to top-down. New demo is up - anyone got any pointers on cleaning up that code please chip in! http://jsbin.com/oseri

Comment: LOL ok... I like trying to figure things out for myself as well. The new version looks like it's working for me without problems in Firefox.

Comment: Cool man, cheers for taking the time to go through it. Seems to run a little sweeter with those changes for sure!

Answer (score 0):

The default value for the height property is `auto`. You should set it to that, instead of `0`, when hiding.